# Cannot read property 'next' of undefined when using async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have a service like this, Which mocks an API call,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscriber} from 'rxjs';

import { DeviceStatus } from '../models/device-status-model';

@Injectable()
export class GetStatusService {
  public deviceStatusObserver: Subscriber<DeviceStatus>;
  public deviceStatus: Observable<DeviceStatus>;

  constructor() { 
    this.deviceStatus = new Observable(observer => {
      this.deviceStatusObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  getRandom(max): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

  callApi() {
    setInterval(() => {
      //Mocking data
      let status = new DeviceStatus();
      status.tempC = this.getRandom(50) + 'C';
      status.tempF = this.getRandom(50) + 'F';
      status.humidity = this.getRandom(100) + '%';
      status.pin1 = true;
      status.pin2 = true;
      status.pin3 = true;
      status.pin4 = true;
      this.deviceStatusObserver.next(status);
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

And a component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


import { GetStatusService } from '../services/get-status.service';
import { DeviceStatus } from '../models/device-status-model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  dStatus$: Observable<DeviceStatus>;

  humidityValue: string; tempValue: string;

  constructor(private getStatusService: GetStatusService) { 
    this.dStatus$ = getStatusService.deviceStatus;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getStatusService.deviceStatus.subscribe((data) => {
       this.tempValue = data.tempC;
       this.humidityValue = data.humidity;
     });
    this.getStatusService.callApi();
  }
}
```

I wanted to use this Observable with async pipe, so i removed

```
this.getStatusService.deviceStatus.subscribe((data) => {
           this.tempValue = data.tempC;
           this.humidityValue = data.humidity;
         });
```

Then I started to get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` on console.
Do I need to subscribe to an Observable even if i use async pipe. All the tutorials i looked up didn't use the subscriber method.

Link to the project in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esp8266-iot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out,

changed added a null check in `callApi()`

```
  callApi() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let status = new DeviceStatus();
      status.tempC = this.getRandom(50) + 'C';
      status.tempF = this.getRandom(50) + 'F';
      status.humidity = this.getRandom(100) + '%';
      status.pin1 = true;
      status.pin2 = true;
      status.pin3 = true;
      status.pin4 = true;
      if(!this.deviceStatusObserver)
        return;
      this.deviceStatusObserver.next(status);
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: I only see the error that comes from `(dStatus$ | async).tempC` changing it to `(dStatus$ | async)?.tempC` throws that error away

Comment: I don't see the error `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` in console on first load http://take.ms/9E1zE